# Pulling series data into HighCharts using Javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, series

I'm having an issue loaded data from a .csv file into Highcharts.

My ultimate goal is to load data from (real sample)

http://maccas.chickenkiller.com/24hr_final.csv

I can get the data into highcharts using a slight variation of the method described in

http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file

The issue is when I use this method I am unable to seperate the different series axis.

My data has series (refer to .csv file above) where 1 set is in the range of 8-9, 3 sets are in the range of 23-30 and the final is in the range of 350-450

My goal would be to move the series "ORP" to a secondary axis (on the right) and "pH" to a tertiary axis (on the left).

I am confident with the options to bind series to primary, secondary and Tertiary axis however I am unable to load the data into the series in a manner that allow this.

Below is the relevant bit of code to produce the "Daily" tab graph

```
$(function () {
    var dailychartoptions = {
        credits: {
            enabled: false
            },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
            },
        chart: {
        renderTo: 'dailychart',
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25,
            zoomType: 'x',
            spacingRight: 2
    },
    title: {
            text: '24hr history',
                x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
            text: 'Temp',
            x: -20
        },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval:60,
            categories: []
        },
    yAxis: [{ //Primary [0]
        title: {
            text: 'orp'
        },
        min: 0
    },
    { //Secondary [1]
        title: {
            text: 'Temp'
        },
        opposite: true
    },
    { //Tertiary [2]
        title: {
            text: 'pH'
        },
        opposite: true
        }],
    tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -10,
//              y: 100,
            borderWidth: 1
        },
    series: []
};

    $.get('24hr_final.csv', function(data) {
// Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
//Below is an attempt to change UNIX EPOCH to Java EPOCH and load into series1 as a date
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) {
                                var javaepoch = (item)/0.001;
                                var date = new Date(javaepoch);
                                dailychartoptions.xAxis.categories.push(date);
                    }
                });
            }
// the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
            else {
                var series = { 
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;
// Added the below to try and set the yaxis value                       
                        if (item = 'pH' ) {
                            series.yAxis = 0;
                        }
// Finished mods for axis

                    } else 
                    {
                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });
                dailychartoptions.series.push(series);
                }
            });
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(dailychartoptions);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is problem:

```
if (item = 'pH' ) { ... }
```

While should be of course `==`. So you can more `if`'s or use better solution: add to each yAxis and ID which will be the same as series name, for example:

```
{ //Tertiary [2]
  title: {
    text: 'pH'
   },
   id: 'pH',
   opposite: true
}
```

Then you can assign name to series as yAxis:

```
if (itemNo == 0) {
  series.name = item;                     
  series.yAxis = item;
}
```

And that's all. If you have any issues - create example on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Big thumbs up.  If I understand where you are heading with the last example of code I should be able to figure it out.  Assuming I can get it working I'll be sure to come back and mark it correct.